# Design best practices for last tracking with indexed view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-design, t-sql

My tables structure is below :

```
  TbDoc (ID int , ...)
  TbDocActions( ID Int, DocID Int, Date DateTime, col1 int, col2 int, ...)
```

I want to have indexed view to get last TbDocActions columns for each `TbDoc` record.
result of this view must be such as below :

```
  DocID , col1, col2, ...
```

For get this result with view I can use below query:

```
Select Z.DocID, X.*
From (Select DocID, Max(ID) as MaxActionID
      From TbDocActions
      Group By DocID
     )Z
inner join TbDocActions X ON X.ID = Z.MaxActionID
```

but I want indexed view to have better performance. and in indexed view I can't use `Max()` aggregate function.

Comment: This is precisely the problem I needed to solve when adopting [this solution](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5692/2660) to the question I asked about [designing a simple bank schema](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/5608/2660).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest solution is as follows: you create an additional column, IsLastID, and build a filtered index or an indexed view using it. You can use constraints to ensure the integrity of IsLastID, as [described here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/yet-another-sql-strategy-for-versioned-data/)

Grant Fritchey wrote up a detailed comparison of various solutions [here](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-strategies-for-versioned-data/)

Comment: This technique perfectly complements [this solution](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5692/2660) to a related design problem.

Answer (score 5):

As you already know, you can't use a `MAX()` aggregate in an indexed view. In any case don't fool yourself into believing that creating an indexed view is a magical performance power button. Depending on your workload, maintaining the indexed view may cost you more performance than you're gaining from the queries against it.

A couple of alternatives might be:

(1) create a non-clustered index on `dbo.TbDocActions(DocID, ID DESC)` or drop the existing clustered index and change it to `DocID, ID DESC`. (If `ID` is an identity column, you've probably also set it up to be the primary key and it will be clustered by default, but that doesn't have to be the case.)

(2) maintain a separate table with the `DocID` as the primary key, and keep the highest `ID` up to date using triggers (or a stored procedure if you are constraining writes to stored procedures only). You will have to have logic for all three DML types (`insert`, `update` and `delete`) because, in theory, any of these could affect the `MAX` calculation. (Less risk, obviously, if both `ID` columns are `IDENTITY`.) You could also add a column to the main table and keep that up to date the same way.

Note that the same caveats apply - adding indexes or maintaining values in other tables might benefit this specific query, but they are not magic - they might affect other parts of your workload. You should always take your entire business cycle into consideration when thinking about "fixing" any single query...