# index of aggregate value with fast update?

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, materialized-view

Is it possible for me to index the sum of a particular table column, such that future lookups will not have to scan the entire table? This table will grow to be very large and a `sum` of the entire table at once could be quite costly.

And just as importantly, can I trigger future `INSERT`|`UPDATE`|`DELETE`s to update the sum without re-adding every term? (For example, an `INSERT` should add the relevant column's value from the new row to the existing sum.)

Will materialized views help with this goal? [This SO question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5608/writing-a-simple-bank-schema-how-should-i-keep-my-balances-in-sync-with-their-t) seems to suggest that they will, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You cannot create an index like that.  However, you can keep a separate table for the aggregate which is then updated on data changes.  One can implement such a system using triggers, for example.  You can use a materialized view, too, but you have to check the performance hit the refresh takes.

Comment: The link is to dba.SE, not SO, and the linked question is for SQL Server, not Postgres. Here is a related answer that's actually for Postgres (and actually on SO): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27629134/postgresql-insert-or-update-values-given-a-select-result-after-a-trigger-has-bee/27630409#27630409