# Designing a bank database schema with multiple balances per account

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema, audit

I'm trying to build a schema to keep a record of the *transactions* made on some *accounts*, but those *accounts* are not "user accounts", instead there are *orders* that are being *paid*, and *money* is being *transfered* by the *buyer* to a *middle man*, and there to the *seller*, so there are **two distinct *balances*** to track.

The problem I have is that I have different kind of *transactions* to track, as the *price* of the *product* can change (affecting the *balance* for both *parties*), the *buyer* can pay *part of the product* (affecting just the *first balance*), or the *buyer* can pay directly to the *seller* (affecting both *balances*). There are more *events* to track (like *canceling the account*, *changing the price of the product to 0 or near 0*, etc).

I've been reading [Writing a simple bank schema: How should I keep my balances in sync with their transaction history?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5608/writing-a-simple-bank-schema-how-should-i-keep-my-balances-in-sync-with-their-t?rq=1) but I'm not sure how does it could apply in this context.

I would like to have a design that provides a *transaction history* easy to read while being flexible to keep track of different *kind of transactions*.

#### Update

I will try to provide more data about the entity types:

The main object is a **Reservation**, that have one **buyer** and one **seller** and a **price** (the buyer have to pay that price, the seller should be payed). It have *two different balances*, one for each.

There are different type of **Transactions** that affect the balances in different ways:

- a Buyer can deposit money to pay part of the reservation,
- money can be sent to the Seller,
- the Buyer can send money directly to the Seller, and
- money can be transfered from one Reservation to other Reservation.

What I'm not sure about, is what is a better approach:

- Store a complex object on the database, that explicit, the kind of transaction, how much money was added/subtracted from which Reservation, if affect buyer and seller, or which one, etc.
- Store multiple simple transactions that just add/subtract from each account. For example, if the buyer send money directly to the seller I would add two transactions, one for each.

Comment: parent account w/ child accounts for the secondary balances?  Try writing it out on paper first and then the solution may become clearer.  You may have two issues.  One is a presentation layer that represents the "fictional" accounts while the true transaction system tracks actual balances.  In that case, meta data (tags, etc.) about each transaction entry could solve the presentation issue.

Comment: Sounds like you want an accounts payable/accounts receivable system of some kind. With the seller being the payable and the buyer being the receivable. And that isn't something that is easy to answer in a question on a stack exchange site as it gets complicated very fast.

Comment: @JonathanFite So, the reservation would have two linked accounts, and the transactions will only affect one account, am I understanding it right?

Comment: @JoeW yes, the systems looks like that, have you any ideas how to model that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ENGINE=InnoDB` and code like this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
Update / insert into one account (one database table, that is)
Update / insert into another account
and any other actions that are tied to this 'transaction'
COMMIT;
```

In some situations, keep two tables for one account:

- "Current" balance, etc
- "History" of what happened -- This should only have `INSERTs`, no `UPDATEs` or `DELETEs`.  It is a blow-by-blow list of all the changes made to arrive at the "current" state that is shown in the other table.

So the "transaction" might include one `UPDATE` to the first table, and one `INSERT` into the other table.